New image in static resource is not displayed in experience cloud site
New image in static resource is not displayed in experience cloud site.
We have replaced the image in static resource but it is not displayed in Experience Cloud site. Looks like it is being loaded from memory cache.
Can we fix this?
How can we fix it?


Is your CDN enabled? If so, try turning it off then later re-enable.

I think yes, we have CDN domain. How can we disable or enable CDN?

Well, you certainly enable it in the digital experience admin setup. I can't remember if you can disable it there too, but have a look.

well, I was able to get it work by including timestamps. But I am curious to discover if we can disable  CDN to fix this

Initially I supposed this was an issue with "Enable secure and persistent browser caching to improve performance" that you'll find in the Setup > Security > Session Settings, but disabling this option didn't help.
Also, it is even more strange that it works like for the standard Salesforce domain like client.my.site.com/support/s/
.home[] {
    background-image: url(/support/sfsites/c/resource/StaticResourceImage);
 }

while for custom.domain.client.com/support/s it doesn't work even though if we follow the link https://custom.domain.client.com/support/s/sfsites/c/resource/StaticResourceImage
and refresh it, a correct image is shown.
The solution or a workaround is to include any timestamp into the URL like following
.home[] {
    background-image: url(/support/sfsites/c/resource/1722331066000/StaticResourceImage);
 }

We can derive that exact timestamp from an Apex code
StaticResource sr = [select LastModifiedDate from StaticResource where ...];
System.debug('>>> ' + sr.LastModifiedDate.getTime());

or hard code it
